# PHP: Multiple ajax request

Tags: php, jquery

I want a code for multiple ajax request. What happens actually is my first ajax request give me the response and in that responce function i m calling another function which having another website url. I want to send data to this new website using multiple ajax request.

Please help me out...
Thanks,
Prafulla

Comment: 'Yes' is no example for what you have done. What is your exact problem with your try?

Comment: if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
 document.getElementById("askquote").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 toOther(name,email,phone); I am calling another function in response of first ajax call is it possible to do this?
 }

Answer (score 0):

use global variables and manipulate your data in each request.
like:

```
var a;
$.ajax({
    url:url_one;
    success: function(data){ a =data; }
});

$.ajax({
    url:url_two;
    data: a //sends the data from the 1st request
    success: function(data){ 
        //do something with the data from the 2nd url
     }
});
```

You can encapsulate your ajax call in function or event handlers as you need.
You can also manuipulate the data returned in variable a before sending it to the 2nd url.
Seems sloppy to me, but sould work.

Comment: I suggest you fix that comment at line 9.

Comment: @Louis Loudog Trottier Do i need to use js file for this to work if yes then tell me the name

Comment: Yes, you will need to use the jquery library. This works on 1.5.1 and up for suare, maybe a few version back too. The actual file i am using is jquery-1.5.1.js